# Как сделать перебор строк в Python

Tags: python, строки, перебор

Мне нужно сделать перебор строк с использованием букв и цифр по порядку, т.е. вывод следующим: aaa, aab, aac,... aaz, aa1, aa2,...aba, abb и т.д, кроме создания переменной на каждый разряд в голову ничего не приходит (хотя это дикие костыли, особенно если строка длинная), так же пробовал использовать itertools, однако он возвращает целый массив всех вариантов, что очень не оптимизированно и не подходит для перебора "на ходу", у меня очень не большой опыт работы со строковыми типами данных в Python и нужна помощь.

Comment: `itertools` работает как генератор, если вы сами не сделаете массив, там будет именно по одному элементу генериться

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
import string
import itertools


letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
for s in map(''.join, itertools.product(letters, repeat=3)):
    print(s)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Решение без `itertools`:

```
import string

iterable = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

print([f'{i}{j}{k}' for i in iterable for j in iterable for k in iterable])
```